# How to check model is update , insert or delete in Yii2

Tags: activerecord, model, yii2

I have a model in Yii. 
How I can identify Yii model is being update, insert or delete after I save it `($model->save() || $model->delete())`?

Comment: Pls can you clarify what you need. Also interact with the Devs that are taking the time to answer your post pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only log what is happening with your models, you may use one of audit trails extensions: [`bedezign/yii2-audit`](https://packagist.org/packages/bedezign/yii2-audit) or [`sammaye/yii2-audittrail`](https://packagist.org/packages/sammaye/yii2-audittrail)

If you want to write your own behavior you may be interested by [`$dirtyAttributes`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#$dirtyAttributes-detail) property which holds attributes that has been changed after save/fetch from database.

Answer (score 3):

With [`$model->isNewRecord`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#$isNewRecord-detail) you can check if the model will be saved or updated. With `($model->save() || $model->delete())` you cannot directly determine what has happend. If `$model->save()` was not successful, then because of validation errors. `$model->delete()` will be called. This will be 1 (i.e. true) if deletion was successfull.

I don't know why you have this statement, but if you cannot change it for some reason and want to know what is going on you could use the [events](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-events):

```
$model->on(yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::EVENT_AFTER_INSERT, function(yii\db\AfterSaveEvent $e) {
    // model was inserted
});
$model->on(yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::EVENT_AFTER_UPDATE, function(yii\db\AfterSaveEvent $e) {
    // model was updated
});
$model->on(yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::EVENT_AFTER_DELETE, function(yii\base\Event $e) {
    // model was deleted
});
```

If you can extend the model class you could overwrite the corresponding methods instead of attaching event handlers. Then you could create a intermediate class that deals with what you need to do, and let derive any model classes from that intermediate class:

```
class ExtendedActiveRecord extends yii\db\ActiveRecord {
    public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes) {
        // Do anything you want
        if($insert)
            // model was inserted
        else
            // model was deleted
        parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
    }
    public function afterDelete() {
        // Do anything you want
        parent::afterDelete();
    }
}

class ModelA extends ExtendedActiveRecord {
    ....
}
class ModelB extends ExtendedActiveRecord {
    ....
}
```

Comment: I want to save all model event for update, delete and insert into log including error message. So i can monitor the record change for this table . So after $model->save()  or $model->delete() can i get event attributes model being insert, update, or delete. Or I must create some variable for this action. Because there is not just one table.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to check when saving. What I mean is that when you save your model, it will return a true/false value, and in the case of a false the model will contain an array or error messages.

That's the easiest way also here you can solve problems, send alerts, print debug info, or do something regarding an error.

```
$model = new MyTable();
$model->name = example;
if($model->save()){
  //Nice its inserted/updated, go ahead
} else {
  //Woops error here, not inserted
}
```

Go ahead, give it a try.

Read more here: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#save()-detail